# Git Commit Error terminal with the editor

Tags: git, git-commit

I'm having some troubles with the command `git commit`. I did a `git commit` but unfortunately I've pressed `Ctrl+Z` instead of `Ctrl+X` to close, so now when I `git commit` again, it gives me this error:

```
error: editor died of signal 11
                           error: There was a problem with the editor 'editor'.   `Please, specific the message using option -m or -F. `
```

Actually I don't know how to fix this error.
The operating system that I'm running is Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're using the nano editor. When you hit `Ctrl+Z` you suspended the editor [something that seems to happen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/467924/how-do-i-get-back-to-nano-after-hitting-ctrl-z-if-i-have-no-shell-prompt).

Now git tells you that your editor is broken. Try to wake up nano by entering `fg` or kill the process with `killall nano`.

Comment: any nano process was found (i've used `killall nano`) and `fg ` did nothing and the bash told me that `fg` is inexistent. So how can I recover it? i've already restarded the PC twice and still giving me that error using only `git commit` command instead of `git commit -m <message>`.

Comment: Ok that is strange a reboot should have recovered you from that. You do use nano right? I tried to replicate your problem and was not successful. Meaning: I did not have the problems you describe when suspending my nano session, I could even suspend two of them and bring them back to live using `fg`. Could you run `man fg` because your bash should have a `fg` built in.

Comment: yes I'm using nano. Actually terminal is telling me that there's no manual for fg, by the way nano process is active but when I use `git commit` it's still giving the same error, so I'm using `-m` option to commit correctly

Comment: So even after a reboot a nano process is running that you didn't start in this session? Strange. Do you know if your nano creates any swap files like vim?

Comment: I don't sorry. I'm new in using Ubuntu and git, and I don't know what vim is sorry... How can I check if my nano creates any swap files?

Comment: Please forget my swap file idea.

Comment: Please run a `ps -A | grep nano` after reboot. It will list all running processes and grep for nano in them. Is there any nano process after reboot?

Comment: No active nano process...it just shows an empty line after that command...`luke@luke-linux:~$ ps -A | grep nano
luke@luke-linux:~$`

Comment: Ok I'm out of further ideas. Sorry

Comment: Don't worry, I'll use `git commit -m "<message>"` to commit correctly. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Another possibility could be to purge nano and reinstall it again. Or you could switch your editor all together.

Comment: it worked!!! i've purged then reinstalled and it worked!! Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: You might add a `~/.nanorc` file with `unset suspend` to disable suspension in Nano.

Comment: Where and how can i add that `~/.nanorc` file with `unset suspend`?

Comment: Use Nano: `nano ~/.nanorc` and enter `unset suspend` save and exit now you shouldn't be able to suspend Nano with `crtl + z`

Answer (score 23):

1. Go to **.git/** folder
2. Delete the file **.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp**

Comment: Please add some explenation to your answer.

Comment: @AndréKool : I actually faced this problem. I noticed that .COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp  was the file which was additional in the .git folder in which I was facing issue as compared to the module in which issue was not occurring. So after removing this file the problem was solved.

Comment: Just ran into this due to a terminal getting closed in the middle of a git merge, which left the swap file `.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp`. Simply deleting it solves the problem.

Comment: This should be the approved answer! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have done a `git add <files>`  or `git rm <files>` then try using `git commit -m  "<commit message>"` instead of opening an editor.

Comment: i didn't add any files, i've just removed one using `git rm <filename>` from my terminal

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your `EDITOR` variable got deleted or reset. To avoid general problems now and in future, set this in your *.zshrc* or *.bashrc*

`export EDITOR=$(which vim)`

Comment: This is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:-
This is for **skip staging and commit**

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```

After remove or add any files, commit with this command:-

```
git commit -m "message"
```

Answer (score 2):

Please set default editor for git using this command
git config --global core.editor "vim"

Here I set Vim editor. It will fix you issue.